# Unity3D: Determine vectors parallel to terrain

Tags: unity, terrain

I am trying to determine vectors that relate the height map information from a Terrain built in Unity to vectors that are parallel to the slope of the terrain.

i.e. From the Unity built terrain, whose contour map looks like the one in the Figure below, I want to draw the vector which is along the slope of the terrain, in the direction that is perpendicular to the contour lines.[image: Definition of parallel vectors.]

How would I do this? I've found a question [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/788782/turn-a-terrain-into-a-contoured-map.html) that includes an answer which supplies code to find the contour lines from a height map.

Does any one know how to find the vectors?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have working code to give you, but you'll need to find the gradient function of your terrain. The rest of the solution is entirely dependent on how you want to display your vectors.